# File uploading using Apollo and Firebase SDK returns broken image

Tags: node.js, firebase, graphql, firebase-storage, apollo-server

I've been going through whole www looking for an answer but I can't seem to find one :(

I have a file upload function where I'm using `createReadStream` which comes from the Apollo Upload scalar type and I want to publish an image to Firebase Storage. It works and I'm not receiving any errors but the image is broken and I'm not able to preview it in Firebase Console. All I can see is an error saying *Error loading preview*. But the filesize, mimetype and accessToken are being uploaded, so i'm doing something right.

Here's my bucket, I am making it available in an Apollo DataSource, that's why I can reference it using `this` in the resolver.

`var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();`

Here's the part of my resolver code where i'm uploading the image:

```
 const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype } = image;

  try {
    await new Promise((res, rej) =>
      createReadStream()
        .pipe(
          this.bucket.file(filename).createWriteStream({
            resumable: false,
            gzip: true,
            metadata: {
              contentType: mimetype,
              metadata: {
                firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuidv4(),
              },
            },
          })
        )
        .on("finish", res)
        .on("error", rej)
    );
    return filename;
  } catch (err) {
    return new Error(err)
  }
```

Am I missing something?

Would really appreciate your help!